# how to get 3sn of audio buffer ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, audiounit

how can I get 3sn of samples of an audio that is being recorded. I have used RemoteIO audiounit and it brings 512 samples and it is 10 milisecond. I need total 3sec of samples? Can you give me an idea how to do it .

here is my another post with details of my code [Concatenating Audio Buffers in ObjectiveC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676988/concatenating-audio-buffers-in-objectivec)

my worst sceneario will be  recording the audio in a file then get its samples. I dont want to go with this.

should I use AudioQueue ?  Any Advice?

I really need help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the buffers (giving to you by the Audio Unit callback) to an array (C array), and increment the index of the array used for saving data by 512 after every 512 samples of input data.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I have tried your method before but it gives an unexpected graph for this method. I have added the outcome in this post. I will really appreciate if you can check and give some advice . you are my only hope. here is the post link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676988/concatenating-audio-buffers-in-objectivec

Answer (score 0):

I have append the frames that came with each render like hotpaw2 said. now you can find the detailed codes, how I applied buffers in my this post/question 
[Concatenating Audio Buffers in ObjectiveC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676988/concatenating-audio-buffers-in-objectivec)

thanks